# how hystrix solve the dependency failure issue

Tags: hystrix

Im new to hystrix..going through the below link

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki

so even if the dependencies(dependency services) are isolated by running in seperate threads and not allowing the failure dependency to use the resource(ex:tomcat) ,the user requests on the application will fail even any of the dependency service is down right..

im not clear how this solves the problem of reducing down time of the application..

Please clarify...correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to wait for a dying endpoint. You can add fallback to get around the issue of not having an available healthy endpoint. Hystrix will keep on probing at predefined rate to check if service is back up and ready to serve in reasonable amount of time.

Comment: ok..but the docs says that dependencies can be wrapped in seperate threads may be using hystrixcommand...but how it works if one dependency service needs input from the result of other dependency..i mean if the service dependencies are dependent..how it will be handled???

Comment: In absence of fallback you potentially can be forever waiting for data. Hystrix gives you tool to handle slower endpoints. It's up to the business requirement of what to do in fallback if an endpoint is not delivering as efficiently as expected.